# How to autofill textbox with the values from postgresql database while typing in node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am trying to autofill the textbox with the database values. But not able to populate the textbox field. I am using node.js, express.js and postgresql database. What I am expecting is when I type in actor first name, I want field to be populated with values from my database. How can I achieve it. Being a newbie to node.js and express. here is my code.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var db = require('pg');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var async = require('async');
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var dbConnection = "postgres://postgres:am@localhost:5432/movie_info";


app.get('/movielist',function(req,res) {
    var dbClient = new db.Client(dbConnection);
    dbClient.connect(function(err){
        if(err)
            throw err;
    var query = "select movie_title from movie";
    var query1 = "select per_fname from person";
    var query2 = "select genre_title from genre";

    //USE ASYNC TO RENDER MULTIPLE QUERIES
    async.series({
        movie: function (movie_list){
                dbClient.query(query,function(err,result){
                movie_list(err,result.rows)
                console.log("select movie query has been executed");
            })
        },
        person: function (person_list){
                dbClient.query(query1,function(err,result){
                person_list(err,result.rows)
            })
        },
        genre: function (genre_list){
                dbClient.query(query2,function(err,result){
                genre_list(err,result.rows)
            })
        }
    },function(err,results){
        if(!err){
            res.render('index.ejs', results);
        }   
    });
});
});


app.post('/submit',function(req,res) {
    var dbClient = new db.Client(dbConnection);
    var movie_title=req.body.movie_title;
    var movie_year=req.body.movie_year;
    var movie_time=req.body.movie_time;
    var movie_lang=req.body.movie_lang;
    var movie_release_date=req.body.movie_release_date;
    var movie_release_country=req.body.movie_release_country;
    var movie_genre = req.body.genre_title;
    var person_fname =req.body.person_fname;
    var person_lname =req.body.person_lname;
    var person_gender=req.body.person_gender;
    var person_role= req.body.person_role;
    console.log('req.body');
    console.log("check: "+req.body.person_fname);
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log("movie to be added: "+movie_title);
    var insert_movie_query = "insert into movie (movie_title,movie_year,movie_time,movie_lang,movie_release_date,movie_release_country) values ('"+movie_title+"','"+movie_year+"',"+movie_time+"   ,'"+movie_lang+"','"+movie_release_date+"','"+movie_release_country+"')";

    var insert_movie_genre_query = "insert into movie_genre(movie_id,genre_id) select movie.movie_id,genre.genre_id from movie, genre where movie.movie_title='"+movie_title+"' and genre.genre_title='"+movie_genre+"'";


    //USE ASYNC TO RENDER MULTIPLE QUERIES
    var person_size = person_fname.length;
    console.log("person length = "+person_size);

    // Function
    dbClient.connect(function(err)
    {
        if(err) throw err;      
        async.series(
        {
            function()
            {
                for(var i=0;i<person_size;i++)
                {   
                    var insert_person_query = "insert into person (per_fname,per_lname,per_gender) values('"+person_fname[i]+"','"+person_lname[i]+"','"+person_gender[i]+"')";
                    dbClient.query(insert_person_query,function(err,result){
                        console.log("if person 2 exists "+result.rows);                     
                    });
                    console.log("person "+i+" has been added");
                }
                //insert movie data
                dbClient.query(insert_movie_query);
                //insert movie_genre data
                dbClient.query(insert_movie_genre_query);
            },

        },function(err,results){
            if (err) throw err;
            res.write("Movie data has been added");
            res.end();
        });
    });
});


app.listen(8080,function(){
    console.log('Server started');
});
```

index.ejs

```
<html >
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="home">
    <h1>Movie list</h1>
    <select class="movie-dropdown" name="movie-list">
        <% for(var i=0; i<movie.length; i++) {%>
            <option class="list-group-item">
                <span></span><%=movie[i].movie_title%>
            </option>
        <% } %>
        </select>
       <br> 
     <h1>Person list</h1>
    <select class="person-dropdown" name="person-list">
        <% for(var i=0; i<person.length; i++) {%>
            <option class="list-group-item">
                <span></span><%=person[i].per_fname%>
            </option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
    <h1>Add movie</h1>
     <form action="/submit" method="POST" name="movie_form" id="movie_form">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="Movie name">Movie Name </label>
                <input type="text" id="movie_title" name="movie_title"  />
                    <br>
                <label for="Movie name">Movie year </label>
                <input type="text" id="movie_year" name="movie_year"  />
                    <br>
                <label for="Movie name">Movie time </label>
                <input type="text" id="movie_time" name="movie_time"  />
                    <br>
                <label for="Movie name">Movie language </label>
                <input type="text" id="movie_lang" name="movie_lang"  />
                    <br>
                <label for="Movie name">Movie release date </label>
                <input type="text" id="movie_release_date" name="movie_release_date"  />
                    <br>
                <label for="Movie name">Movie release country </label>
                <input type="text" id="movie_release_country" name="movie_release_country"  />
                    <br>    
                <label for="Movie genre">Movie genre </label>
                <select class="genre-dropdown" name="genre_title" id ="genre_title">
                        <% for(var i=0; i<genre.length; i++) {%>
                        <option class="list-group-item">
                            <span></span><%=genre[i].genre_title%>
                    </option>
                <% } %>
                </select>
                    <br>
                <label id ="person_fname" for="person fname">person first name </label>
                <input type="text" id="person_fname_text" name="person_fname"  />
                <label id ="person_lname" for="person lname">person last name </label>
                <input type="text" id="person_lname_text" name="person_lname"  />
                <select name='person_gender' id='person_gender'>
                    <option value="M" id ="m" name="m">M</option>
                    <option value="F" id ="f" name="f">F</option>
                </select>
                <select name='person_role' id='person_role'>
                    <option value="ACTOR" id ="role_actor" name="role_actor">ACTOR</option>
                    <option value="DIRECTOR" id ="role_director" name="role_director">DIRECTOR</option>
                    <option value="PRODUCER" id ="role_producer" name="role_producer">PRODUCER</option>
                </select>
                <button type="button" onclick="add_person()">Add person</button>                    
                <br>
                 <div id="person_container"></div>
                <input type="submit" value="add_movie" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </section>
</body>
</html>


<script>
function add_person()
{
    //var index = $("#person_container").length + 1;

    var fname_label = $("#person_fname").clone();
    var fname_textbox = $("#person_fname_text").clone();
    var lname_label = $("#person_lname").clone();
    var lname_textbox = $("#person_lname_text").clone();
    var gender_dropdown = $("#person_gender").clone();
    var role_dropdown = $("#person_role").clone();

    gender_dropdown.attr("id","person_gender");
    gender_dropdown.attr("name","person_gender");

    role_dropdown.attr("id","person_role");
    role_dropdown.attr("name","person_role");

    $("#person_container").append(fname_label);
    $("#person_container").append(fname_textbox);
    $("#person_container").append(lname_label);
    $("#person_container").append(lname_textbox);
    $("#person_container").append(gender_dropdown);
    $("#person_container").append(role_dropdown);
    $("#person_container").append("<br>");
    var abc = $("#person_container select").length;
    console.log(abc);
}
</script>
```